# Postgres SQL WHERE clause with 'OR' in pattern match

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have strings of `010xxx, 011xxx, 110xxx, 111xxx, Q10xxx, Q11xxx` in a field along with other values that are not similar. They might be `XyzABC`.

I have two regex patterns that separately give results that are good: `[1Q]_[0-9]%` and `0_[1-9]%`

In words return true if

```
first letter is 1 or Q and the 3rd letter is a 0-9 

OR 

the first letter is 0 and the third letter is 1-9
```

How do I create a search pattern that does the OR either using SIMILAR TO or regex?

One version that works by itself is:

```
SELECT field FROM db WHERE field SIMILAR TO '[1Q]_[0-9]%'
```

Not wedded to SIMILAR or regex. They were just what I could get working until I tried to `or` them. Open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`SIMILAR TO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP) pattern like

```sql
WHERE field SIMILAR TO '([1Q]_[0-9]|0_[1-9])%'
```

The SIMILAR TO pattern requires a full string match, so the pattern means: start with `1` or `Q`, then any char, then any digit, or start with `0`, any char and a non-zero digit, and then there can be any 0 or more chars afterwards.

You can also use a regex like

```sql
WHERE field ~ '^(?:[1Q].[0-9]|0.[1-9])'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FyUVx7/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[1Q].[0-9]` - `1` or `Q`, any char and a digit
- `|` - or

  - `0.[1-9]` - `0`, any char and a non-zero digit
- `)` - end of a non-capturing group.

Comment: `SIMILAR TO` is internally converted to `~` automatically, so both versions are equally good.

Comment: Use the `SIMILAR TO` version and it worked. My problem was making the patter "readable" by putting spaces around the `|`.  I was  using https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/postgresql/index.html for testing but will keep the other site in mind.  Thanks. Up voted and marked as answer.